# Rails display bootstrap modal of index from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have two models groups and shots. From my groups #show page, I want a modal window that will allow me to display a list of all my shots. Here is the relevant code...

## app/views/groups/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Add Exsisting Shot", shots_path, id: "shot-modal", remote: true %>
```

## app/views/shots/modal.js.erb

```
$("#shot-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'modal') %>")
$("#shot-modal").modal("show")
```

## app/controllers/shots_controller.rb

```
 def index
    @shots = Shot.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @shots }
    end
  end
```

When I click the 'Add Existing Shot' link, I do a a model that sort of turns the who screen gray, but I am not getting any content. I can click anywhere on the screen, it it brings me back to my show page. I'm also not getting any errors in the console.

## EDIT

## app/views/shots/_modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="shot-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="shot-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="shot-modal-label">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="shot-modal-body">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Comedian</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>

        <% @shots.each do |shot| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= shot.name %></td>
            <td><%= shot.comedian.name %></td>
            <td><%= image_tag shot.pic.url(:thumb) %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1 - If you have a modal like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="product-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="product-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="product-modal-label">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="product-modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you should not use `$("#product-modal").html(...` because you will overwrite a lot of the important `div`s in the modal. You should use `$(".modal-body","#product-modal").html(...` or set the id for the modal-body as above and use `$("#product-modal-body").html(...`.

2 - The render won't work. When you run the render command like that from a view, it is looking for a partial. So your JavaScript should actually look like something like this:

```
$("#product-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'allshots') %>")
```

And then you should put the HTML for displaying your shots in `app/views/shots/_allshots.html.erb`.

Comment: Thanks mccannf...this is helpful. See edits/additions I added above. When I click my link I get a gray screen, but I'm not seeing any content.